# How can I change an account picture for another user without logging in as that user?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have what is essentially a service account called "scanner" on my Windows 10 computer.  It was set up by an IT Contractor.  I am an administrator and the Scanner account is not.  How can I change the picture for the account without logging into that account?

Comment: You can't.  So the simplest solution.  Make `scanner` an Administrator, change the profile, then change the `scanner` back to a User.

Comment: Well that sucks.

Comment: Try manipulating the picture files in C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures. I don't have windows 10 to verify so I didn't put it in the answer.

Comment: There is no profile since the account has never been logged in interactively, which is one of the things I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: If there's no account then how can there be an account picture?  Is it using one of the default pictures in: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\Default Pictures?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Fr2IrV6.png is what it looks like.